# Define a stop wordlist into an analyser with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, stop-words

I'm trying to add a list of stop word to my mapping but I get an error. This is the mapping:

```
PUT test-recipe
{
  "mappings": {
    "recipe" : {
      "properties" : {
        "ingredients" : {
          "type" :    "string",
          "analyzer": "english",
          "stopwords": ["my", "stop", "words"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This mapping works fine without the stop words parameter. But with the stop words field I get the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Mapping definition for [ingredients] has unsupported parameters:  [stopwords : [Best®, Halves, organic, island, free, gluten, high-gluten, segments, baking, cooking, new, active, dry, leaves, slices, sliced, warm, root, hot, jack, extract, slivered, sliver, non-fat, fat, chopped, skinless, seed, nonfat, melted, cracked, in, split, vegetable, smoked, medium, nectar, all-purpose, fraîche, fresh]]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [recipe]: Mapping definition for [ingredients] has unsupported parameters:  [stopwords : [Best®, Halves, organic, island, free, gluten, high-gluten, segments, baking, cooking, new, active, dry, leaves, slices, sliced, warm, root, hot, jack, extract, slivered, sliver, non-fat, fat, chopped, skinless, seed, nonfat, melted, cracked, in, split, vegetable, smoked, medium, nectar, all-purpose, fraîche, fresh]]",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
         "reason": "Mapping definition for [ingredients] has unsupported parameters:  [stopwords : [Best®, Halves, organic, island, free, gluten, high-gluten, segments, baking, cooking, new, active, dry, leaves, slices, sliced, warm, root, hot, jack, extract, slivered, sliver, non-fat, fat, chopped, skinless, seed, nonfat, melted, cracked, in, split, vegetable, smoked, medium, nectar, all-purpose, fraîche, fresh]]"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

If you could tell me why I got this problem it will make my day. Moreover is that stop words list will be taking in account when doing my "more like this query"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create filter for stop words and use it in your analyzer

```
#remove index
#DELETE recipe

#put mapping, analyzer and filter for stop words
PUT recipe
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "cooking_nonstop": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "english_morphology",
            "my_stopwords"
          ]
        }
        },
        "filter": {
          "my_stopwords": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords": "Best®,Halves,organic,island,free,gluten,high-gluten,segments,baking,cooking,new,active,dry,leaves,slices,sliced,warm,root,hot,jack,extract,slivered,sliver,non-fat,fat,chopped,skinless,seed,nonfat,melted,cracked,in,split,vegetable,smoked,medium,nectar,all-purpose,fraîche,fresh"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "recipe": {
        "properties": {
          "ingredients": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "cooking_nonstop"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

#check analyzer
GET /recipe/_analyze?analyzer=cooking_nonstop&text=put+fresh+egs+in+hot+water

#create document
POST recipe/recipe/boiled_egs
{
  "ingredients":"put fresh egs in hot water"
}

#another stop word filter demonstration
POST recipe/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ingredients",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've got the following error: Custom Analyzer [cooking_nonstop] failed to find filter under name [english_morphology]

Comment: You right, just remove it from "cooking_nonstop" analyzer, or install it from [here](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology). I is copy/paste issue =)